# Html.render doesn't work in azure virtual machines

Tags: python, azure, web-scraping, azure-virtual-machine

I need to do some web scraping and I'm using the render method from requests_html.HTMLSession since the page uses JavaScript. When I run the script in my pc it works perfectly, but I need to be able to run it in a azure virtual machine and it doesn't work cause it never ends and throws this "Exception raised from browser". Could you help me please?

Code of interest:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

...

def get_page_content(link):
    s = HTMLSession()

    response = s.get(link)
    response.html.render(timeout=30, reload=False) #Here is where it fails.

    s.close()    

    return response.text
```

Thank you

Comment: is it same browser you are using in your local PC and your azure VM for rendering the script?

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you try with this code.

```
from requests_html  import HTMLSession

session  =HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://www.cnblogs.com/pythonywy/')

print(response.html.render(keep_page=true))

async def run():
    # interactive statements 
    await r.html.page.XXX

 

try:
    session.loop.run_until_complete(run())
finally:
    session.close()
```

Reference: https://www.codestudyblog.com/cnb11/1124173502.html

and follow this GITHUB discussion for same: https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/294